# Firebase FCM server php-android

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I created a simple php code to send a notification to my android devices which have google log in method from firebase implementation. Their tokens are already stored in my database. When I execute my php, it doesn't send the notification. Whoever , if i send a notification trough firebase notification console it works. This is my php code .

```
function sendGCM($message, $registration_ids) {
    //FCM URL
    $url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
//prepare data
$fields = array (
    'registration_ids' => array ($registration_ids),
    'data' => array ("message" => $message)
);
$fields = json_encode ( $fields ); 

//header data
$headers = array ('Authorization: key=<YOUR_API_KEY>', 'Content-Type: application/json');

//initiate curl request
$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );

// execute curl request
$result = curl_exec ( $ch );

//close curl request
curl_close ( $ch );

//return output
return $result;
}
```

Error:
when I execute this php file, throw this error:

```
{

    "multicast_id": 5359746182596118281,
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
    {
    "error": "InvalidRegistration"
    }
                ]
    }
```

Comment: Have you look on google for your problem ? There is a whole page about firebase error code [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) You should try to do some research before posting on Stackoverflow. Also, It's ok not to show your API key here, but make sure it's set in your code, in the headers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to find Reference\_Ids for Firebase Cloud Messaging?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278459/where-to-find-reference-ids-for-firebase-cloud-messaging)

Comment: Possibly because you are passing an array in registartion ids so that it becomes array of array which is incorrect. Try sending a single string token id and it should work. i have already got it working.

Comment: single string? that sounds interesting, I will try it and tell you if it works

Comment: I already tried it and it is not that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
    <?php

// API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'your_key' );
$registrationIds = array($id); //$id is string not array


// prep the bundle
$notification = array
(
    'title'     => 'title',
    'body'      => 'body',
    'icon'      => 'logo',
    'sound'     => 'default',
    'tag'       => 'tag',
    'color'     => '#ffffff'

);

$data = array
(
    'message' => 'message body',
    'click_action' => "PUSH_INTENT"
);

$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'notification'      => $notification,
    'data'              => $data,
    'priority'          => 'normal'

);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: Thank you , I will aply it to my php file and tell if it works

Comment: Hello, i already tried but It says de same error. invalid registration,  define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'your_key' ); here i just need to change the word my key?

Comment: @xx_name : Yes, you need to input you key you got from Firebase console. You can find it in the Firebase console settings under Cloud messaging. I currently use the legacy server key, but firebase recommends usage of server key. you can try both.

Comment: Hello everyone, I already saw my error, it was because i was using googles log in tokens instead firebase tokens, my bad. I misunderstood the documentation, thank you helped me